# Look for a location of a file in two places bash linux

Tags: linux, file, bash, search

I'm looking to do this in one command in bash:

```
[[ -f ./${SQLITE} ] || [ -f /tmp/${SQLITE} ]]
```

Not sure how to do it  yet ....  look for a file in two places... in one command.

Comment: `[[` is technically not a command, it is a keyword. `[` is a command, but this can not be done in a single `[` command, only `[[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `]` and `[` that is not needed:

```
[[ -f ./${SQLITE} || -f /tmp/${SQLITE} ]]
```

Comment: You could also say he's missing some brackets: `[[ -f ./${SQLITE} ]] || [[ -f /tmp/${SQLITE} ]]`, but that's a little uglier.